# Solaris: Offline a disk at a low level, without rebooting

Tags: solaris, hard-drive

In Solaris, if I unplug a couple disks while the machine is running, some functions that check every disk will take awhile because it has to wait for the timeout.

For example `format` or `zpool import` both read all the disks as one of the first things they do.

I counter-act this sometimes by the following: (I do of course replace zero with the correct numbers)

`cd /dev/dsk`, `mkdir offline`, `mv c0t0d0* offline`,
`cd ../rdsk`, `mkdir offline`, `mv c0t0d0* offline`.

At this point I can do whatever I want with `format` and `zpool import` and it will be much faster.

When the disks are re-inserted, I can then online them again with

`cd /dev/dsk`, `mv offline/* .`, `rmdir offline`,
`cd ../rdsk`, `mv offline/* .`, `rmdir offline`.

Is there a command for this? One that temporarily removes the symbolic links for a specified disk, as well as a way to put them back?

I am very happy with the solution I found. Especially because this machine is an offline machine, I can risk this level of manipulation. (for example, if I actually typed zero in the real thing, there would be trouble)

However, I would like to know about a better way if there is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct method is to use the `cfgadm` command to unconfigure the device before unplugging it. The [ZFS Administration Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcet/index.html) has an example of this procedure (of course, you can ignore the ZFS steps if you're not using ZFS).

Example from the guide pasted below:

```
# zpool offline tank c1t3d0
# cfgadm | grep c1t3d0
sata1/3::dsk/c1t3d0            disk         connected    configured   ok
# cfgadm -c unconfigure sata1/3
Unconfigure the device at: /devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7458@2/pci11ab,11ab@1:3
This operation will suspend activity on the SATA device
Continue (yes/no)? yes
# cfgadm | grep sata1/3
sata1/3                        disk         connected    unconfigured ok
<Physically replace the failed disk c1t3d0>
# cfgadm -c configure sata1/3
# cfgadm | grep sata1/3
sata1/3::dsk/c1t3d0            disk         connected    configured   ok
# zpool online tank c1t3d0
```

Comment: In this example you will also need to run #zpool replace command to get your new disk in a good state else your new disk will be recognized but in a faulty state.